# How can I record the position where the user pressed the mouse button with Python and GTK?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I would like to let the user of my application draw something. Which signal / event do I use for that?

This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk


class DrawingAreaExample:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Drawing Area Example")
        window.set_default_size(800, 600)
        window.connect('button-press-event', self.callback)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        self.area = gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.area.set_size_request(400, 300)
        self.pangolayout = self.area.create_pango_layout("")
        self.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.sw.add_with_viewport(self.area)
        self.table = gtk.Table(2, 2)
        self.table.attach(self.sw, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        window.add(self.table)
        self.area.connect("expose-event", self.area_expose_cb)
        self.area.show()
        self.sw.show()
        self.table.show()
        window.show()

    def callback(self, window, event):
        self.draw_point(int(event.x), int(event.y))

    def area_expose_cb(self, area, event):
        self.style = self.area.get_style()
        self.gc = self.style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
        return True

    def draw_point(self, x, y):
        # self.area.window.draw_point(self.gc, x, y)
        self.area.window.draw_arc(self.gc, True, x, y, 5, 5, 5, 360*64)


def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DrawingAreaExample()
    main()
```

Comment: Is this for GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3?

Comment: And do you come from GTK+ 2, or are you using some other learning resource? I ask this because `expose-event` is the GTK+ 2 way of drawing; it has been changed since, and I want to point to the most appropriate documentation for your scenario.

Comment: @andlabs This is the first time I make anything with GUI (outside of the web environment). I want to use GTK+ 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it to work. Thanks to http://zetcode.com/gfx/pycairo/basicdrawing/ for the tutorial which helped me a lot!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Write on a canvas, store on-line data."""


from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import time
import math
__version__ = '0.1'


class FormulaWriter(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FormulaWriter, self).__init__()
        self.odata = []  # On-line writing information, grouped by strokes

        # General properties
        self.set_title("Formula Writer %s" % __version__)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        # Set up canvas
        self.canvas = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.canvas.connect("draw", self.on_draw)
        self.canvas.connect("button-press-event", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas.set_events(self.canvas.get_events() |
                               Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_MOTION_MASK |
                               Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK |
                               Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON2_MOTION_MASK |
                               Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON3_MOTION_MASK |
                               Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)

        self.add(self.canvas)
        self.show_all()

    def on_button_press(self, w, event):
        """When a button is pressed, the location gets stored and the canvas
        gets updated.
        """
        self.odata.append([{'x': event.x, 'y': event.y, 'time': time.time()}])
        self.canvas.queue_draw()

    def on_mouse_move(self, w, event):
        """When mouse is moved, the mouse position gets stored."""
        point = {'x': event.x, 'y': event.y, 'time': time.time()}
        self.odata[-1].append(point)
        self.canvas.queue_draw()

    def on_draw(self, wid, cr):
        """Handler for drawing action. Draw all strokes.
        :param wid: The DrawingArea
        :param cr: Context
        """

        cr.set_source_rgb(1, 0, 0)  # All strokes get drawn in red
        cr.set_line_width(2.5)

        for stroke in self.odata:
            for i, point in enumerate(stroke):
                if len(stroke) == 1:
                    radius = 2
                    cr.arc(point['x'], point['y'], radius, 0, 2.0*math.pi)
                    cr.fill()
                    cr.stroke()
                elif i != 0:
                    cr.move_to(stroke[i-1]['x'], stroke[i-1]['y'])
                    cr.line_to(point['x'], point['y'])
                    cr.stroke()


def main():
    FormulaWriter()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`button-press-event` is correct, but you want to hook it up to the GtkDrawingArea, not to the GtkWindow. You'll also need `motion-notify-event` to handle mouse moves during the button press.

[The tutorial here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html) will show you how to do what you want to do. There are a few other slight problems with your code (such as the use of `expose-event` instead of `draw`) that this code should show how to do right. Unfortunately it's in C; IDK if [the Python GTK+ 3 tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) has the same example.

Comment: When I change it to `self.area.connect('button-press-event', self.callback)` nothing happens at all.

Comment: Did you add a call to `GtkWidget.set_events()` or `GtkWidget.add_events()`? The code sample I linked says "Ask to receive events the drawing area doesn't normally subscribe to. In particular, we need to ask for the button press and motion notify events that want to handle." GtkDrawingArea's documentation will also point this out.